# check if .click() function is available in browser

Tags: javascript

I am building an application that uses `.click()` method in couple of places. It was reported that it causes errors in safari (windows version) because its not available in the browser.

I made some research and i found good alternative, i created a polyfill solution for it, but i am struggling to find how can i check if browser supports `.click()` method.

I tried following:

- `Element.prototype.click` returns undefined in all browsers
- `Element.click` returns undefined in all browsers
- `document.prototype.click` returns undefined in all browsers
- `document.click` returns undefined in all browsers

This is the polyfill i made:

```
Element.prototype.click = function() {
    var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    click_ev.initEvent("click", true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */);
    this.dispatchEvent(click_ev);
};
```

Now i just need to check it and apply only if `.click()` is unavailable.

Comment: As far as I know `click()` is supported everywhere. Check: http://caniuse.com/#search=click

Comment: `if ('click' in document.documentElement)`; ?

Comment: `HTMLElement.prototype.click` might be what you're after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the event exist for a new created dom element:

```
if (!document.createElement('div').click) {
  Element.prototype.click = function() {
    var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    click_ev.initEvent("click", true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */);
    this.dispatchEvent(click_ev);
  };
}
```

Comment: @PatrickMevia: If this answers your question, mark it as solved!

Comment: sure ill do ;) i just cant yet, it says in 5 min i will be able to, btw this answer is the best because its in global scope, really good!

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].click will also work, why create a new element

Answer (score 1):

You can validate `yourElment.click`

```
if(!(yourElment.click)){
    // click doent exist
    Element.prototype.click = function() {
    var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    click_ev.initEvent("click", true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */);
    this.dispatchEvent(click_ev);
 };
}
```